# Оборот "в связи" в середине предложения

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, нужно ли в этом случае обособлять оборот с "в связи":

*Как(,) в связи с объявлением 31 декабря выходным днем(,) должны переносить сессию студентам?*

Спасибо!

Comment: Вполне можно и без запятых обойтись. Откуда такое желание их поставить?

Comment: Спасибо. На грамоте. ру было написано: "Запятая ставится только в том случае, если оборот, начинающийся предлогом в связи с, носит характер присоединительного (если перед этими словами есть интонационная пауза). Если паузы перед этими словами нет, запятая не нужна".  Я бы тоже не стала ставить, но решила проверить. И теперь в тупике, ставить или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В связи с* - производный  составной предлог,часто входящий в состав обстоятельственного оборота. Это никак не вводное сочетание, потому что является в предложении обстоятельством причины. Для проверки его можно заменить на синонимический **производный  предлог «по причине»**  или непроизводный **из-за.**

*Как в связи с объявлением 31 декабря выходным днем должны переносить сессию студентам?* (*Как из-за  объявления 31 декабря выходным днем должны переносить сессию студентам?*)

Сочетание «в связи с» чаще всего употребляется в официально-деловом и публицистическом стиле **в начале утверждения, вывода или сообщения.**

*В связи с ремонтными работами вода будет отключена на неопределённый срок.* (По причине ремонтных работ вода будет отключена на неопределённый срок).

*В связи с недостаточностью улик дело было закрыто.*
(По причине недостаточности улик дело было закрыто).

Если предложный оборот находится в середине простого предложения, то запятая тоже не ставится.

Мы отменили прогулку (по какой причине?) в связи с ухудшением погоды.

Бывает так, что данный предлог находится зрительно в середине предложения, но на самом деле он является началом простого предложения в составе сложного. В этом случае запятая ставится перед предлогом, но не как выделительная, а как разделительная - она отделяет друг от друга простые предложения.

*Дождь пошел, в связи с этим мы не пошли на прогулку.*

Приведённая Вами конструкция - вопросительное предложение, **где вопросительное слово оторвали от сказуемого, но оборот всё равно - обстоятельство причины.**

Прямой порядок слов: *Как должны переносить сессию студентам в связи с объявлением 31 декабря выходным днем?* (из-за объявления 31 декабря выходным днем; по причине объявления 31 декабря выходным днем).

Если бы это была присоединительная конструкция или пояснение, оборот можно было бы убрать из предложения без потери смысла. Попробуем это сделать:

*Как должны переносить сессию студентам?*

Смысл изменился, стал неясным. О каком переносе идёт речь? Следовательно, это важная часть конструкции этого предложения, не вставная или вводная конструкции и не пояснительная или присоединительная. **Причин для постановки запятых нет.**